# Convert epoch milliseconds to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, timestamp, nsdate, epoch

I want to convert milliseconds elapsed since Jan 1 1970 to NSDate without loosing milliseconds. Every solution says to divide milliseconds by 1000 and use dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970. but I want to keep the preserve the to milliseconds as well.

Comment: please elaborate more or put some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` is a `NSTimeInterval`, which is not an integer value (it's a `double`). There's no reason to lose milliseconds. Just don't use integers when you perform your division.

For example:

```
long long milliseconds = 1576058147753;
NSTimeInterval seconds = (NSTimeInterval)milliseconds / 1000.0;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:@"dMMMMyyyyHHmmssSSS"];
```

> December 11, 2019, 01:55:47.753

Note the milliseconds of 753 are there.

Comment: This func will always lost milliseconds, the milliseconds will alwayz be +0000, your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Kira - That is simply not true. You lose µsec, but not milliseconds. The milliseconds are most certainly not always zero. E.g., `NSTimeInterval` of 1576058147.753, for example, yields a date of `2019-12-11T09:55:47.753Z` (note the milliseconds). If you have code where your milliseconds are zero, then your problem rests elsewhere. Or if you're just printing the date and seeing a `+0000` at the end, that's the timezone, not the milliseconds. Change to a formatter that includes milliseconds.

Comment: you are right! I miss the µsec but not milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can get date in this way.You have to pass timeinterval and date format as per your requirement.

```
-(NSString *)getStringFromDate:(double)interval withFormat:(NSString*)format
{
    if (interval == 0)
    {
        return @"";
    }
    double seconds = interval;
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = (NSTimeInterval)seconds;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

    NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
    [df_utc setDateFormat:format];
    NSString *Date=[df_utc stringFromDate:date];
    return Date;
}
```

Hope this will help you.